# Android: How to set a listener for Acivity.onNewIntent()?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listener, android-lifecycle

I'm writting my own plug-in for an existing game engine (so to say it's 3rd-party lib in relation to the main application).

So, I have no access to the `MainActivity` sources.

Nevertheless I have to react somehow on main activity `lifecycle` events (`onCreate, onDestroy, onPause, onResume, onNewIntent` and some unimportant others).

Thanks to `Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`, I have no problems with most of them.

The problem occurs with [onNewIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29). I can't find out a `listener` for this event and imagine a way to handle it.

Does anybody know how to catch `onNewIntent` event (surely, except overriding it)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

onNewIntent() works for **singleTop** or **singleTask** activities which already run somewhere else in the stack. if the MainActivity is not declared with singleTop or singleTask attributes, even if you use below code, it won't work:

```
@Override //won't be called if no singleTop/singleTask attributes are used
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) { 
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // ...    
}
```

To assure all setup logic hooked, it is best use onResume() by utilizing getIntent().

```
@Override
protected void onResume() { //will be called in any cases
    super.onResume();
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent        
}
```

Comment: Obtaining intent in onResume and comparing it with previous one sounds like a not bad idea.  If intents are different I can do what I have to do for the new intent. A lag is admissible in my case. Accepted. )

Comment: Did this work? According to the javadoc for `Activity.onNewIntent`: "Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent."